# How to achieve slim athletic physique?

Tags: strength, muscle-recovery, athletic-performance

I’m 17 years old and i’m street dance dancer. I feel like athletic training is the best way how to cover my needs and body goals. Im going for really strong muscles but kinda skinny physique. Something like that:
[image]

Also tips on faster recovery and how much should I workout. Now im skinny, 14 body fat procentage, 69 kg and 182cm. Im grateful for every help and tip.

Comment: That image is not a exactly a "kinda skinny physique" and probably required quite a bit of training and dieting to achieve

Comment: Anyway, kinda hard to give you advice on how to improve without knowing exactly what training you're already doing, unless you want the cookie cutter "start with weights 3× a week, increase protein blabla" kind of answer...

Comment: I don’t wanna be skinny but i don’t wanna be big, thats what i meant by that. Im dont really understand these things i’ve never got into working out. I’m just dancing a lot i would say 10+ hours per week. Thats probably why im so skinny. I guess that u can count it as cardio i don’t really know. I think that stronger and better physique would help me get better at dancing and it would increase my confidence thats why im trynna get into it.

Comment: Probably want to start with body weight exercises like pushups, pull ups etc, not exactly my main field of expertise. However, getting "too big" is super hard to do. Granted I'm a girl, but I've been on the quest to get huge af for years and training hard all the time and I'm not there yet. I don't think getting too big is something to worry about if you're just starting training.

Comment: okay thank you that makes sense. So i should just create my own bodyweight body workout for now right ?

Comment: I'm sure you could find some good free starter program online, or just wait a while longer, I'm sure the bodyweight people on here can help you out

Comment: @Nicolas -- as someone else who *wants* to be big, let me tell you, it really does not happen accidentally. Just like always_confused said, years of training + eating and I'm also not there yet. So, feel free to hit the heavy weightlifting movements too.

Comment: The main aspect to not getting too bulky is to either not eat too many calories which will stunt muscle growth, or focus on strenth rather than hypertrophy. Gain a respectable amount of muscle, then do a cutting routine to cut the fat off, than use a maintanence routine for as long as you want to keep that body.

Comment: and should I stop doing cardio and dancing for a little bit ? is it bad to do cardio while gaining muscle ? I think that i heard that somewhere